# Just insert a new key - value on a mysql json field on Laravel

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

I work with Laravel and I try to add an entry to a MySQL field in JSON format ...

This field contains (for example), this:

```
        {
            "df2jay22p1f1nb31b161jf2jay22p5":
            {
                "type": "texte-image",
                "contenu": "Texte de test",
                "position": "2"
            },
            "df2jay1w251p1nb31a2f24f2jay1w256":
            {
                "type": "contenu-seul",
                "contenu": "Contenu de test",
                "position": "1"
            }
        }
```

My goal is to arrive at this:

```
            {
            "df2jay22p1f1nb31b161jf2jay22p5":
            {
                "type": "texte-image",
                "contenu": "Texte de test",
                "position": "2",
                "image": "/url/to/img.jpg"
            },
            "df2jay1w251p1nb31a2f24f2jay1w256":
            {
                "type": "contenu-seul",
                "contenu": "Contenu de test",
                "position": "1"
            }
        }
```

My controller works like this:

```
$page = new Page();
        $page->contenu = $request->input('composants'); // Json field
        $page->save();

        foreach($page->contenu as $i => $element){
            if ( $request->hasFile("composants." . $i . ".image") ){
                $image =  $request->file("composants." . $i . ".image");
                // ... image processing, save on directory, etc... 
            }
        }
```

I would therefore like to take up the content of

```
$page->contenu
```

and add the value of "image" to it but I can't realize it ...

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Read the docs on [JSON_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that you can adapt to your code:

```
$json = '{
            "df2jay22p1f1nb31b161jf2jay22p5":
            {
                "type": "texte-image",
                "contenu": "Texte de test",
                "position": "2"
            },
            "df2jay1w251p1nb31a2f24f2jay1w256":
            {
                "type": "contenu-seul",
                "contenu": "Contenu de test",
                "position": "1"
            }
}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$arr['df2jay22p1f1nb31b161jf2jay22p5']['image'] = "/url/to/img.jpg";
$json = json_encode($arr);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
echo '</pre>';
```